# Search CSV column 'city' for values on supplied list.csv with header column 'city'. if found delete

Tags: perl

I have about 10-20K records and only need certain cities.  I would like to make this work in perl but i can't seem to find an example of just what i need.  searchme.csv and list.csv if city is found delete record/row.  I was sorting and splitting the screen but now there is just way to many to hand pick out.  Please any help would be much appreciated.  Im only a nueb.

1. searchme.csv contains rows with 'name,address,city,state,zip,phone' with header.
2. list.csv contains 1 row with header 'city' and 50+ rows of the cities that I want to keep.
3. So for each row in searchme.csv get the 'city' into a $variable and loop thru the list.csv if match found write the full row from searchme.csv to new file new.csv.  the more i play with this i got it to loop over the searchme.csv, i think i need to load the cities.csv into and array and loop thru the array within the while loop. and if found print to new.csv.

Comment: This is a good module: http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV.pm

Comment: I'm a little confused by your description.  Could you re-write your description as a numbered list of steps?

Comment: i'm trying to compare 1 *.csv to another the csv doc being compared is only going to have a list of cities that i want to keep and if it's not on the list remove it.  I was looking around and Yes squiguy i have been playing with Text::CSV but now i was looking and i found this

Comment: use strict;
   use warnings;

   use Tie::Handle::CSV;

   my $csv_fh = Tie::Handle::CSV->new('basic.csv', header => 1);
   
   print $csv_fh->header, "\n";

   while (my $csv_line = <$csv_fh>)
      {
      $csv_line->{'salary'} *= 1.05;  ## give a 5% raise
      print $csv_line, "\n";          ## auto-stringify to CSV line on STDOUT
      }

   close $csv_fh;

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~danboo/Tie-Handle-CSV-0.14/lib/Tie/Handle/CSV.pm    I found an example that seems like a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't quite tell from your last comment whether you're still working on this, or not.  In any case, here's a solution to consider.

```
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use autodie qw(:all);

# slurp files into arrays
open my $RECORDSFILE, '<', 'searchme.csv';
my @records = <$RECORDSFILE>;
close $RECORDSFILE;

open my $LISTFILE, '<', 'list.csv';
my @citychecklist = <$LISTFILE>;
close $LISTFILE;

open my $NEWFILE, '>>', 'new.csv';

my $cityidx = 2;
my $item;
my $record;

# loop through each record and extract the city string
foreach $record (@records) {
    my @data = split qr/,/, $record;
    my $city = $data[$cityidx];
    # skip the header
    next if $city eq 'city';

    # compare the city string with each city in our other list
    foreach $item (@citychecklist) {
        chomp $item;
        # if we find a match write out the record to another file
        if ($city eq $item) {
            print {$NEWFILE} $record;
        }
    }
}

close $NEWFILE;
```

Comment: Thank you so much i'm gonna give it a try

Comment: Globalsymbol "$record" requires explicitpackagename atcheckit.pl line13.Globalsymbol "@data" requires explicit package name at checkit.pl line 14.Global symbol "$record" requires explicit package name at checkit.pl line 14.Global symbol "@data" requires explicit package name at checkit.pl line 15.Global symbol "$item" requires explicit package name at checkit.pl line 20.Global symbol "$item" requires explicit package name at checkit.pl line 21.Global symbol "$item" requires explicit package name at checkit.pl line 23.Global symbol "$record" requires explicit package name at checkit.pl line 24.

Comment: sry i had to trim spaces to get it all in

Comment: Global symbol "@data" requires explicit package name at checkit.pl line 14.
Global symbol "@data" requires explicit package name at checkit.pl line 15.
Execution of checkit.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: I updated, then quickly updated again.  I think you missed my second update.  Should work if you try again.

Comment: Subroutine main::io redefined at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/IO/All/Base.pm line 24.
that what i get now

Comment: i had use IO:ALL twice i have strict and warnings and it runs but no warnings and no new.csv

Comment: You had to use `IO::All` twice?  Not sure what you mean.  You must run the script in the same directory where `searchme.csv` and `list.csv` are located.  Are those filenames correct?

Comment: yea i had the use IO::ALL on the script twice removed one.  file names are correct in same folder runs without errors and without new.csv\

Comment: Seems like you're having problems with `IO::All` for some reason, so I rewrote the script using traditional perl file io, which doesn't require any modules.

Comment: new.csv comes out blank getting closer

Comment: Hmmmm.... that doesn't sound right.  Works perfectly on my system.  Maybe there's a problem with your CSV files?  Can you open both of your CSV files in Excel and see all of the data?  You should see one row for every record.  So, if you have 50 records, you should see 50 rows in excel.

Comment: think i have to problem with my csv lemme test some more ill get back to u thanks for you help i really really appreciate it.

Comment: Ok - good luck.  Maybe you could give me a bump on the up arrow for my answer (i.e "answer is useful").  Thanks.

Comment: @StevenG Excellent!  Glad it worked.  If you could, please award my response with "answered".  Thanks.

Comment: i would but i don't have enough rep

Comment: If you have a website or a link I can post on my company website would be more than glad to.

Comment: @StevenG Thanks, that's very generous, but I just do this for personal interest.  By the way, if you're interested, you might try going back to the `IO::All` solution now that you have your CSV files sorted out.  I'd be curious to know whether it works now.